# show/hide entities matching time window in Drupal7 using views 3.7 and exposed filter

Tags: drupal-7, view, combinations, drupal-exposed-filter, computed-field

I am using D7 and views. I have an entity that has Date type attributes valid_since and valid_until. I have implemented a view that can show these entities. I want to add a checkbox (exposed filter) on the views page which (if checked) would show *only* entities that are currently valid and vice versa. In essence I need some kind of a filter combo and disable/enable that combo.
I tried using computed field module but at the moment its value can only get stored to the database and it does not compute on the fly. Any guidelines ?